# Hazelcast getSql().execute() throws Unrecognized client message received with type: 0x210100

Tags: java, spring, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am trying out Hazelcast client-server.
So far, I

- Got up hazelcast server members
- Create a spring boot application and connected to hazelcast
- Inserted/updated/queried Imap in hazelcast instance
- Used SQL Predicate to query map objects

Now I am trying to run an sql query on the object (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/sql/distributed-sql) but couldn't make it work. Am I missing something here ? Do I need to do something else ?

My bean

```java
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig().setEnabled(true);
    ClientUserCodeDeploymentConfig distCLConfig = clientConfig.getUserCodeDeploymentConfig();
    List<String> classNames = new ArrayList<>();
    classNames.add("com.varane.models.Student");
    distCLConfig.setEnabled(true).setClassNames(classNames);
    return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
}
```

My model

```java
package com.varane.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Model class for students
 */
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String contact;

    public Student(){}

    public Student(Integer id, String name, String contact) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", contact='" + contact + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And my controller

```java
@Autowired
private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

@GetMapping("/sql-test")
void sqlTest(){
    SqlService sqlService = hazelcastInstance.getSql();
    sqlService.execute("SELECT * FROM student");
}
```

Dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.210'
    implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast'
    implementation 'com.hazelcast:hazelcast-sql:4.2.4'
}
```

When I hit the endpoint this is error I get on server (500)

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unrecognized client message received with type: 0x210100
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.NoSuchMessageTask.processMessage(NoSuchMessageTask.java:45) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.initializeAndProcessMessage(AbstractMessageTask.java:153) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.protocol.task.AbstractMessageTask.run(AbstractMessageTask.java:116) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at ------ submitted from ------.() ~[na:na]
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.ExceptionUtil.cloneExceptionWithFixedAsyncStackTrace(ExceptionUtil.java:279) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.returnOrThrowWithGetConventions(InvocationFuture.java:112) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:95) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:40) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:614) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.sql.impl.client.SqlClientService.invoke(SqlClientService.java:215) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.sql.impl.client.SqlClientService.execute(SqlClientService.java:96) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.hazelcast.sql.SqlService.execute(SqlService.java:144) ~[hazelcast-4.1.5.jar:4.1.5]
    at com.varane.controllers.StudentController.sqlTest(StudentController.java:95) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: What is the version of Hazelcast server you are using?

Comment: Hi, Version: 5.1 ($ hz -V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a compatible version on the client-side. While the 4.x client is mostly compatible with 5.x, the SQL feature was in BETA until 5.0. So you should use 5.0 or newer.

In Spring boot you can just add the following property to override the version, if you are using Maven:

```
<hazelcast.version>5.1</hazelcast.version>
```

or Gradle:

```
ext['hazelcast.version'] = '5.1'
```

Comment: didn't imagine this to be a version problem. this worked, thanks a lot.